# java scp ssh file copy to remote dir

Tags: java, file-io, ssh, scp

I am using ssh scp to send file from local dir to a remote dir using 0755 mode. I want to know whether this will overwrite the existing file with the same name or do I have to put a check for that?!
I am using this library for that purpose. http://www.ganymed.ethz.ch/ssh2/
suggestions needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will overwrite the existing file.

Comment: Even if the file had been created previously by another user and given 400 permissions?

Comment: Ah, that may not work: if you have permissions to it, you will overwrite it. If you don't have permissions, your write will fail (noisily or silently depending on your settings).

Comment: thanks for the reply..but what you mean by permissions!? U mean permissions to access that remote folder?!

Comment: If you have write permissions to the file (i.e. whichever user is ssh'ing in can write to the file because that user either owns the file, is in the group that owns the file and the file has the group write permission set, or the file is world-writable) you will overwrite it. If you do not have write permissions then it will fail.